# Is there a German equivalent to the Oxford English Dictionary (OED)?

Tags: etymology, resource, dictionary, online-resource

I have been searching for something like the German equivalent to the OED, which provides amazing etymological speculation and historical information on most English words.  Bonus for a web version that has clickable links that can take me down an etymological rabbit hole.  Double bonus for something that can live in my phone.

(Note: I am by no means fluent in German but do know basic vocabulary and grammar that I am able to investigate German poetry and philosophy that interests me.)

Comment: Did you already go through the links from this question & answer here: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3/is-there-a-good-online-resource-to-look-up-the-etymology-of-german-words?

Answer (score 3):

See previous question here 
[Is there a good online resource to look up the etymology of German words?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/3/18653)

I most often use [dwds.de](http://dwds.de) and like the dashboard feel to each page, and that you have so many different resources for each word. Take a look!

Answer (score 3):

The Grimm [Deutsches Wörterbuch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsches_W%C3%B6rterbuch) is the standard historical dictionary of German, though quite different in format to the *OED* as it was started earlier. The [first edition is online for free.](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/) For historical reasons, the section A–F is not quite up to the same standard as the rest and is currently being [revised](http://dwb.bbaw.de/) for a second edition, due to be completed in the next few years (but sadly not currently available online except a [few example entries in the range F–*Fasnacht*](http://www.dwb-digital.adw-goettingen.gwdg.de/grimm/index.html)). The new section is much more like the *OED* than any of the old edition, but unfortunately due to funding difficulties [the letters G–Z will not be updated again.](http://www.welt.de/kultur/article4127427/Es-war-einmal-das-Woerterbuch-der-Grimms.html)

Comment: That's some sad information.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my answer and giving valuable detail.

Answer (score -1):

No, unfortunately there is no German dictionary that contains as much information and is as easy to use as the OED (where I refer to the “real” OED, which does not have free access).

Comment: Some people seemed to be unsatisfied with my answer. I can only imagine that they found the second sentence irrelevant, so I have deleted it and concentrated on giving an answer. I am looking forward to the up-votes that will now surely roll in.