# School slang: „Der Pauker“ und „blau machen“

Tags: meaning, slang

Ich glaube, *der Pauker* bedeutet *der Lehrer*.

Ich habe auch „Ich mache  blau“ für „Ich werde nicht in der Klasse sitzen“ gehört.

Ist das die richtige Interpretation?

Comment: Are you looking for any information that can't be found in a [dictionary](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-good-online-dictionaries-for-translation-between-german-and-english)?

Answer (score 11):

Ein Pauker ist ein Lehrer. Im [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Pauker) wird die Herkunft kurz erläutert:

> [gekürzt aus Arschpauker, eigentlich = jemand, der beim Unterrichten Schläge auf das Gesäß austeilt] (Schülersprache) Lehrer

Die Redewendung "blau machen" bedeutet generell, bei etwas nicht anwesend zu sein, obwohl man es eigentlich muss, vor allem Arbeit und Schule.

> Ich habe heute keine Lust, ich mache blau.

Comment: Pauker ist unfassbar antiquiert.

Comment: Jetzt wird's wieder modisch, sowie das 60er Jahre Design, kommt immer wieder zurück..

Answer (score 9):

> Ich glaube, es bedeutet Der Lehrer.

**Correct.** And yes, it is colloquial.

But it has almost vanished, at least from colloqial language. The [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Pauker,pauken&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,Pauker;,c0;.t1;,pauken;,c0) shows it's usage is diminishing also in literature (while pauken - surprisingly - has increased recently):

**Edit**: Note that **pauken** is (amongst other meanings) [colloquial for **lernen**](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/pauken) (not **lehren**)

[image]

Concerning **blau machen** I think there's nothing to add to what has been said.

Answer (score 1):

*blau machen* heißt prinzipiell, seinen Verpflichtungen nicht nachzukommen.

Die Redewendung kommt vermutlich vom arbeitsfreien Montag der Handwerker (auch als [Blauer Montag](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blauer_Montag) bekannt).

Comment: 'blau machen' may be derived from the profession of  of dyer/dipper. When the dyers needed to wait for the indigo color to develop they had nothing to do: cf. https://www.wissen.de/raetsel/woher-kommt-der-begriff-blau-machen