# Unterschied zwischen 'die Quellenangabe' und 'der Literaturnachweis'?

Tags: word-choice, difference, noun

Leo listet mehrere mögliche Übersetzungen für [references](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&p=DOKJAA&search=references&trestr=0x8001), darunter

> die Empfehlungen  Pl.
>   die Hinweise  Pl.
>   der Literaturnachweis
>   die Quellenangabe

Ich brauche das Wort für akademische Dokumente oder Präsentationen. Aufgrund von Anwendungsbeispielen auf Linguee für [*Literaturnachweis*](http://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?source=auto&query=Literaturnachweis) und [*Quellenangabe*](http://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?source=auto&query=Quellenangabe), denke ich,  dass diese beiden Wörter die richtige Wahl sind.

1. Liege ich da richtig oder was ist die richtige Wahl für akademische Dokumente?
2. Und ganz allgemein: Die *Empfehlungen* sind *recommendations*, *Hinweise* ist mehr wie *details*. Die Bedeutung von *Quellenangabe* ist ganz ähnlich zu *Literaturnachweis*. Stimmt das?

Comment: Recommendation: Don't use Leo too excessively. They do have some good translations, but unfortunately also a lot of nonsense. (Just as a general hint; I don't know what word you looked up to get those suggestion, they all might be correct in that case)

Comment: Its not nonsense Leo has - they simply offer the most frequent translations for [*"reference"*](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=reference) but will fail like any dictionary when we don't give them a context like searching Leo for [*"reference list"*](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=reference+list).

Comment: @Takkat Das stimmt. Kontext ist wichtig, ein Buch oder ein "Werkzeug" ist nicht genug. Ich habe viele Duden, Langenschaft, PONS usw. Mehr [hier](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/4972/887).

Comment: @Em1: Steht doch da: references.

Answer (score 9):

Ein (wie auch immer benanntes) Literaturverzeichnis verzeichnet nur Literatur: Bücher, Aufsätze, Internet-Blogs usw. Ein Quellenverzeichnis kann prinzipiell jede Art von Quelle verzeichnen, so z.B. auch Bildquellen (Abbildungen), Tonquellen (für Audiodateien), Archäologische Funde in Museen usw.

Manche Fachbücher verwenden sowohl "Literaturverzeichnis" (für die verwendete Literatur) als auch "Quellenverzeichnis" (für die aus anderen Veröffentlichungen oder von Bilddatenbanken übernommenen Abbildungen und Tabellen), so z.B. Schmidt-Atzert, L. & Amelang, M. (2012). *Psychologische Diagnostik*. Berlin: Springer.

Obwohl "Quellenverzeichnis" für ein Literaturverzeichnis nicht grundsätzlich falsch ist, würde ich deshalb für eine reines Verzeichnis von Büchern und Zeitschriftenartikeln die Bezeichnung "Literaturverzeichnis" bevorzugen.

Als Überschrift für das Literaturverzeichnis am Ende eines wissenschaftlichen Artikels sind folgende Bezeichnungen gleichermaßen üblich:

- Literatur
- Literaturverzeichnis
- Verwendete Literatur

"Literaturnachweis" empfinde ich als ungebräuchlich und würde es persönlich nicht verwenden.

Comment: +1 gut, mehr Alternativen :)

Answer (score 4):

**Quellenangabe**
Wenn man eine wissenschaftliche Arbeit schreibt, dann fügt man in den selbstgeschriebenen Text häufig wörtliche Zitate ein, die aus anderen Texten stammen (meist von anderen Autoren, aber man kann auch eigene Arbeiten zitieren). Oder man gibt sinngemäß etwas wieder, das man in einer anderen Arbeit gelesen hat. In beiden Fällen muss man angeben, dass diese kurzen Abschnitte nicht das Werk eigener Arbeit sind. Man muss also zwei Dinge tun:

1. Das wörtliche oder sinngemäße Zitat als solches kennzeichnen.
2. Direkt beim Zitat eine Quelle angeben.

Nur dadurch ist es möglich, genau nachzuvollziehen, woher jedes einzelne Zitat stammt.

Es würde den Lesefluss aber erheblich stören, wenn nach jedem Zitat (und seien es nur drei Wörter) ein zweizeiliger Verweis auf die genaue Stelle in einem bestimmten Werk folgen würde. Daher kürzt man die Quellenangabe meist ab. Dafür gibt es mehrere unterschiedliche Standards. Geisteswissenschaftler verwenden als Kürzel häufig den Nachnamen des Autors und das Erscheinungsjahr der zitierten Arbeit. Naturwissenschaftler und Techniker vergeben stattdessen gerne laufende Nummern. Dahinter kann (muss aber nicht) eine Seitenzahl angegeben sein.

Zwei erfundene Beispiele:

- "Ziel der atonalen Musik ist die Auflösung tonaler Zentren." (Meier 1952, S. 18)
- "Objective-C ist eine Erweiterung der Sprache C." [5]

Die Bestandteile "(Meier 1952, S. 18)" und "[5]" sind Quellenangaben.

**Literaturverzeichnis**
Mit der Angabe "[5]" allein wird man die tatsächliche Quelle nicht finden. Daher fügt man ans Ende der Arbeit eine Liste mit den genauen Verweisen zu den zitierten Literaturstellen an. Die Einträge in dieser Liste beginnen mit genau jenen Kürzeln, die in den Quellenangaben verwendet wurden (häufig auch in fetter Schrift gesetzt), gefolgt von der Angabe des vollen Namens des Autors, des Titels des Werks, dem Erscheinungsjahr, dem Verlag, bei Artikeln aus Sammelwerken dem Namen der Sammlung, der Seitennummer und möglicherweise einer Reihe weiterer Angaben.

Weil die gekürzte Quellenangabe direkt beim Zitat nur zusammen mit einem Eintrag im Literaturverzeichnis einen Sinn ergibt, werden manchmal auch die Einträge im Literaturverzeichnis selbst als Quellenangaben bezeichnet. Wer mag, kann darüber mit jemandem, der den jeweils anderen Standpunkt vertritt, sehr lange diskutieren, ohne zu einer Einigung zu gelangen.

Die Einträge im Literaturverzeichnis müssen nicht zwingend auf bedrucktes Papier verweisen. Es ist auch möglich z. B. auf Filme oder Medien aus dem Internet zu verweisen, vorausgesetzt, diese Quellen erfüllen vom Inhalt her die geforderten wissenschaftlichen Standards und sind (im Fall von Internet-Medien) garantiert permanent unter der angegebenen Adresse auffindbar.

**Literaturnachweis**
Synonym für Literaturverzeichnis

**weiterführende Literatur**
Besonders bei größeren Arbeiten (z. B. Büchern) kennt der Autor möglicherweise eine Reihe anderer Quellen, die sich auch mit demselben Thema beschäftigen, ohne dass er daraus Zitate für seine eigene Arbeit verwendet hat. Wenn er möchte, kann er diese Werke in einer separaten Liste, unter dem Titel "weiterführende Literatur" anführen. Auch das ist ein Literaturverzeichnis, aber darin befinden sich keine Quellen für die vorliegende Arbeit.

Answer (score 2):

Nach meiner persönlichen Erfahrung werden *Quellenangabe* und *Literaturnachweis* synonym verwendet. Man kann den entsprechenden Abschnitt im Text oder in der Präsentation auch einfach mit *Quellen* bzw. *Literatur* betiteln, das ist genauso üblich. *Quellenangabe* bzw. *Quellen* ist etwas breiter gefasst und kann auch Sachen umfassen, die nicht *Literatur* sind (Fernsehen, Internet, persönliche Gespräche, ...). Aber es ist nicht falsch, *Quellenangabe* oder *Quellen* zu schreiben, wenn man nur *Literatur* im klassischen Sinne meint und keine anderen Quellen auflistet.

Answer (score 1):

Nach meiner Erfahrung wird in den Geisteswissenschaften der Unterschied zwischen *Quelle* und *Literatur* am stärksten betont:

- Quelle: ist das Original
- Literatur: ist ein Aufsatz/ Artikel/ Buch über eine Quelle

D.h., die Originalausfertigung der US-Verfassung ist eine Quelle. Ein Buch, dass unter anderem die Originalausfertigung der US-Verfassung als Bild oder buchstabengetreu den Text abdruckt, ist eindeutig Literatur.

Somit bedeutet "Quellenarbeit" auch, das Original zu untersuchen & daraus zu zitieren.

[Anstelle zw. Quelle und Literatur](http://waste.informatik.hu-berlin.de/Lehre/ws1112/PS_WissArbeiten/handout_031111_vortrag2.pdf) wird auch unterschieden in

- Primärquelle = das Original
- Sekundärquelle = zitieren aus dem Original / thematisiert das Original

  - kann zur Primärquelle werden
- Tertiärquelle = zitieren aus der Sekundärquelle

Damit wird ein Nachdruck der US-Verfassung selbst zur Quelle mit dem notwendigen Hinweis in der Quellenangabe von wann und wem sie ist.

In den anderen Wissenschaftsgebieten ist andere Fachliteratur dann die Quelle und z.B. selbst erhobene [empirische] Daten und daher eher eine synonyme Verwendung von *Quellenverzeichnis* und *Literaturverzeichnis*, da selten Fachliteratur über Fachliteratur genutzt wird.

Die Art und Weise der Quellen-/ Literaturangabe ist von dieser Einteilung per se unberührt und Gegenstand eigener Debatten. Da geht es u.a. um Verweis oder im Fließtext (Fußnote/ Endnote, runde Klammer / eckige Klammer, Nummer/ Kürzel / Kurzangabe/ Vollangabe).

Einzige Einigekeit besteht darin, dass die Angaben im Fließtext sich eindeutig zuordnen lassen, ob über die Zwischenstation Quellen-/ Literaturverzeichnis oder nicht.

D.h. für Deine eigentliche Frage: geht beides, kommt auf den Kontext an (der hier in der Frage fehlt).

Answer (score 0):

Ich habe einige Beispiele. Ich weiß nicht das richtige Wort für *references* im akademischen Kontext. Vielleicht sind beide möglich: *Quellenangabe* und *Nachweis*. Es gibt viele verschiedene *Nachweise*, so z.B. *Literaturnachweis*.

*Nachweis* bedeutet *die Richtigkeit einer Behauptung darlegen*, während das Wort *Quellenangabe* ganz neutral ist. Ich denke, die anderen Wörter, wie *Hinweise*, bedeuten etwas ganz anderes.

**Quellenangaben**

> - `"Die Quellenangaben stehen am Schluss des Aufsatzes."` (PONS iPad)
> - `"ein Text, den man wissenschaftlich verwertet oder in einen anderen Text zitiert"` (Langenscheidt iPad)
> - **Ursprung mit `Quellwasser`?** `"Quellwasser"` ist `"der Ursprung eines Baches oder Flusses: der Lauf der Donau von der Quelle bis zur Mündung"` (L)
> - **Ursprung mit `Quell`?** `"eine Stelle, an der Wasser aus der Erde kommt"` (L)

[image]

*[Ursprung des Bildes](http://wasserspender-hamburg.de/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/Fotolia_3206135_XS.jpg)*

**Nachweis** (~proof)

> - "die Dokumente, mit denen man etwas nachweisen kann" (L)
> - Beispiele sowie "Identitätsnachweis", "Literaturnachweis" und "Befähigungsnachweis" (certificate of competence)

Comment: Warum ein "-1"? Ist etwas falsch?

Comment: Es spricht nichts dagegen, eigene Fragen zu beantworten, aber das meiste, was du hier geschrieben hast, gehört eher in die Frage selbst. Formulierungen wie "Ich weiß nicht" und wiederholte Verwendung von Ausdrücken wie "Ich denke" und "Vielleicht" schwächen deine Aussage noch ab. Zumal du z.b. auch nicht erläuterst, warum denn "Hinweise" deiner Meinung nach etwas anderes bedeutet. Ich frage mich jetzt "Was bedeutet es denn nun?" Deine Antwort enthält teils schon richtige Ansätze, aber ist zu lückenhaft. Auch dass du eine Stelle zitierst, in der von "Identitätsnachweis" die Rede ist, ... (tbc)

Comment: ... welche zwar in einer Aufzählung mit "Literaturnachweis" steht, aber hier natürlich off-topic ist und somit eher wieder die Frage aufwirft, was das nun eigentlich ist, und ob es jetzt was mit akademischen Arbeiten zu tun hat, oder doch nicht?

Comment: Side note: Ich habe bei meiner Editierung versucht, neben den Tippfehlern, auch weitesgehend semantische Verbesserungen einzupflegen, ohne dabei aber deine eigentliche Aussage zu verändern. Es fiel mir nur unheimlich schwierig immer deine eigentliche Aussage zu verstehen. Ich wollte schon heute morgen den Text korrigieren, bin aber immer wieder gestolpert, da teilweise die Aussagen kontextlos erscheinen. Der erste Satz zum Beispiel hat da gar nichts zu suchen, zumal du in deiner ganzen Antwort kein Beispiel anführst. - However, ist keine bösgemeinte Kritik; nur eine Anregung für nächstes mal;)

Comment: @Em1 Entschuligung aber Ich kann dich nicht verstehen. Ich denke es ist wichtig ächliche Sachen zu analysieren und es hilft mir die Ursprungen zu sehen :)