# German phonetics tools?

Tags: translation, spelling

I am new to learning the German language. From time to time I need to look at how the word is spelled in phonetics. Is there a free resource where I can write in the word and get the phonetical version of it?

Comment: See http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3237/german-dictionary-with-detailed-declensions-audio-pronunciations-and-ipa - personally I like [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Hauptseite) a lot (which was mentioned in the question, hence not in an answer).

Comment: @Takkat: Wo genau hat Eva in ihrer Frage *Wiktionary* erwähnt?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Die verlinkte Frage erwähnt Wiktionary...

Comment: @Takkat: Thank you for your response. I highly appreciate you taking time to answer my question.

Comment: @Eva: your question may soon be linked as a dupe to the question/answer I gave above. As stated we still very much miss an answer about Wiktionary there. If you have the time it would be cool to post such an answer there e.g. giving us a short example with a screenshot (and maybe explain why you still wrote about Wiktionary even if it was excluded in the question body).