# German/English dictionary with native audio for Android?

Tags: dictionary

I'm learning German and I'm not sure who the accurate German dictionary publishers are...in English there are dictionaries that always have too many errors such as Collins. So, what publisher should I move toward to ensure updated, always accurate definitions? I need this on my Android phone. Any tips? On the other hand, if no such thing is available is there a Windows French dictionary with native pronunciation?

I prefer for-pay dictionaries as I hate ads and I want something updated frequently.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the dictionaries in our [list of online dictionaries](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-good-online-dictionaries-for-translation-between-german-and-english?rq=1) also provide a similar app for Android. Below are two examples of free apps with audio recordings:

- [Leo dictionary](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.leo.android.dict&hl=en)
- [Dict.cc dictionary](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cc.dict.dictcc&hl=en)

For listening to professional audio recordings on pronunciation there also are the non-free [Duden Android apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.duden.container&hl=de) which come in various editions but they are German only dictionaries.