# Recommended German-English Dictionaries

Tags: dictionary, online-resource

I would like to have German dictionaries that include plural forms, genitive forms, articles and verb conjugations as well. So far I have not found a single dictionary containing all these functions, if there is such a dictionary I would like to hear about it. It can be on the net, printed or available as a separate program and I would prefer a German-English and English-German dictionary.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: See http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3237/german-dictionary-with-detailed-declensions-audio-pronunciations-and-ipa and http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-good-online-dictionaries-for-translation-between-german-and-english for your special need I'd highly reccommend http://www.canoo.net/

Comment: You'll find comprehensive conjugation and declension lists on Wiktionary.

Comment: @Em1 Thanks for your suggestion I will look it up.

Answer (score 4):

I believe www.dict.cc covers all those bases, doesn't it?

Comment: It does. Not all of these are listed necessarily at first search, some can be found (i.e., Flexionstabellen) by right-clicking on entries.

Comment: @Milchgesicht and OP I think there should be a better dictionary providing the accompanying auxiliary verbs, for example.

Answer (score 0):

https://itunes.apple.com/ie/app/one-world-dictionary/id464285660?mt=12

One world dictionary does not cover all your needs, but I find it good enough for me.